# Is it okay to place other tag outside the html tag using include?

Tags: php, html

For example:
mainpage.php - contains the html, head and body tags.

```
<?php include('otherpage.php') ?>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
        Contents.....
   </body>
 </html>
```

otherpage.php - 
In otherpage.php contains some buttons and text.

```
   <nav>
       <div>Text or buttons here....</div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: No all that should be within the `<body>` tag

Comment: your `include('otherpage.php')` must be put in to your Contents

Comment: If it is html code then it should be inside `html` code. In case of `php`, it could be placed anywhere according to requirement.

Comment: You can do that, every framework has its own way to include other files, that is good for code maintaince and code reuse.

Comment: @Armin but you cannot place it outside the `<body>` tag unless you want it to be completely ignored by the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly Most browsers just adapt if you du such an error. But that does not mean it's a good idea to base a webpage on a browsers adaptabillity.

Comment: the otherpage.php page contains html and php codes. I already apply it on my project and so far I have not encounter any problem I just want to know if there are any instances that will affect the system in the future. btw thanks for all opinions

Comment: Simple rule - if you output html, put it in your body, if not, it can go wherever you like

Comment: In that case I say Yes. It can affect the system in the future. Do it right or not at all. All you need to do is remove the html tags from the includes that is not supposed to be there and make sure to include at the correct place and not at the top of the page.

Comment: Further to what Andreas says, the problems it can cause can be subtle; hard to spot and debug. For example, if you increased the amount of html in otherpage.php it could suddenly stop a browser from correctly recognising the character set of the page so it shows maybe `Â£` where you intended `£`.